# how to make QListWidgetItem NOT tristate?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I've got a form with a QListWidget, into which I repeatedly add new items. It all woks flawless, except for on thing: the items are tristate whatever flags I pass them. Consequently the item must be clicked twice to check/uncheck them. What should I do to make them normal dual-state?

The widget is created thus:

```
def _locationDetails(self):
    self.locationDetails = QListWidget()
    self.locationDetails.setFixedHeight(50)
    return self.locationDetails
```

end the items are added as follows:

```
def addLocationDetail(self, text, checked = True):
    item = QListWidgetItem(text)
    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable    |
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item.setCheckState(checked)
    self.locationDetails.addItem(item)
```

The code by which I invoke the addition of new items reads:

```
    # resolve location:
    waypoint.getLocationDetails()
    self.locationDetails.clear()
    self.addLocationDetail("location=%s"    % waypoint.location)
    self.addLocationDetail("department=%s"  % waypoint.department)
    self.addLocationDetail("country=%s"     % waypoint.country)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because the [`setCheckState()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#setCheckState) function needs a value from the [`Qt::CheckState`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#CheckState-enum) enumeration:

> **enum Qt::CheckState**
>
> This enum describes the state of checkable items, controls, and widgets.
>
> Constant  Value   Description
>
> `Qt::Unchecked`          0    The item is unchecked.
>
> `Qt::PartiallyChecked`   1    The item is partially checked. Items in hierarchical models may be partially checked if some, but not all, of their children are checked.
>
> `Qt::Checked`            2    The item is checked.

And since you are passing it a `True` value by default, it is converted to `1` which corresponds to `Qt::PartiallyChecked`.

A possible solution is to use the Boolean value to an appropriate value of the type `Qt::CheckState`:

```
def addLocationDetail(self, text, checked=True):
    item = QListWidgetItem(text)
    item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable |
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable    |
                  QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked if checked else QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
    self.locationDetails.addItem(item)
```

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thanks.